# How to fix 'addEventListener' not working in Violentmonkey or Tampermonkey Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, console, addeventlistener, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I want a button to be automatically clicked after 0.1 seconds after entering 5 characters in a textbox....

This code works correctly in the console(developer.F12) section of the browser. But I want this code to be executed permanently in the browser by Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey extension.

```
var textbox = document.getElementById("Text");

var button = document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0];

textbox.addEventListener("input", function() {
  var inputText = textbox.value.trim();
  if (inputText.length === 5) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      button.click();
    }, 100);
  }
});
```

But This is not working in Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey Chrome extension....

Please see this picture:

[image]

How can I run this code in the Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey Chrome extension?

---

Update:

In response to **Alexander Nenashev**:

Let me explain what I want to use this code for.
For example, I want the login button to be automatically clicked on every website page in the login section after entering a 5-digit password.
And also these elements are present on the site
I import this code through the browser console of the developer section (F12), it works, but as soon as the page is refreshed, I have to import this code again, and my problem is exactly here. I want this JavaScript code permanently in the background of every site. I want it to be active, and according to my research, the tampermonkey extension seems to do it, but not for me!

[image]

I put your code in the Tampermonkey extension, but unfortunately I got the same error as before... And we have the elements available on the desired website

Answer (score 1):

Your error's explanation:
`document.getElementById("Text");` returns `null` since there's no such textbox on the page yet when you run your monkey script.
When you run your code in the console the elements are present so you have no problems.

I believe a monkey script runs after `DOMContentLoaded`. But...
The page could create elements after this (for example loading some chunk of HTML from the backend and inserting into the page). So...
You should watch the page for the needed elements. The simple way is to use `setTimeout()` to run your code a bit later hoping the elements are here. And possible repeat the process, stopping when the elements are found.

But there's a more *elegant* approach. In my monkey scripts I use `MutationObserver`:

```js
// emulate code on the page

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {

  e.target.remove();

  document.querySelector('.container').innerHTML = `
    <input id="Text">
    <button class="btn">Auto click me</button>
    <div class="log"></div>
  `;

  const textbox = document.querySelector('#Text');
  textbox.focus();

  document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('.log').innerHTML += `<div>${textbox.value.trim()}</div>`;
    textbox.value = '';
  });
  
});

// your code, watch for body mutations and add listeners;

let observer = new MutationObserver(addListener);

/*
  if you have more specific container where to look and 
  it's present on DOMContentLoaded - use here.
*/
observer.observe(document.body, {childList: true, subtree: true});

function addListener(){

  const textbox = document.querySelector('#Text');
  const button = document.querySelector('.btn');

  if(!textbox || !button){
    return; // not on the page yet
  }

  textbox.addEventListener('input', () => {
    textbox.value.trim().length === 5 && setTimeout(() => button.click(), 100);
  });
  
  // stop observing since you've attached the listener
  
  observer.disconnect();
  observer = null;

  // stackoverflow's console.log() mutates DOM so use it after disconnecting
  console.log('the listener has been added');

};
```

```html
<button>Add elements</button>
<div class="container"></div>
```

**UPDATE**

If an event bubbles you can catch it at the `document`:

```js
// emulate code on the page

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {

  e.target.remove();

  document.querySelector('.container').innerHTML = `
    <input id="Text">
    <button class="btn">Auto click me</button>
    <div class="log"></div>
  `;

  const textbox = document.querySelector('#Text');
  textbox.focus();

  document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('.log').innerHTML += `<div>${textbox.value.trim()}</div>`;
    textbox.value = '';
  });
  
});

// your code, watch for inputs to change

document.addEventListener('input', e => {

  const button = document.querySelector('.btn');

  e.target.value.trim().length === 5 && setTimeout(() => button.click(), 100);

});
```

```html
<button>Add elements</button>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: I put your code in the Tampermonkey plugin, but unfortunately I got the same error as before...
And we have the elements available on the desired website

Comment: @Mjniyazi pls give me the link to a site you like this code to work with. and which text input

Comment: @Mjniyazi you can try to handle events at the document, i've updated the answer

Comment: Yes, Sure. Just how can I send you the site link privately? Is this site possible for me to send you the site link confidentially? I ask because I'm a freshman...

Comment: @Mjniyazi you could contact me silentmantra.ru@gmail.com . also pls check some simpler solution i've added to my answer

Comment: I used the new solution, but the same error as before was repeated.
Please check your email.
Thank you.